# Function to Remove WooCommerce Product Tag on Schedule

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got a function that adds the tag "New" to products that are newly published based on the `woocommerce_new_product` hook.

```
// Add New Tag to new Products
function jsd_tag_on_product_save( $product_id ) {
    //ADD THE PRODUCT TAG
    wp_add_object_terms($product_id, "New", 'product_tag');
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_product', 'jsd_tag_on_product_save', 10, 1 );
```

This works fine but I'm also trying to remove the tag at a later date. I first get the "New" tagged products in an array and order by date:

```
//Get products by tag
    $new_product_ids = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'New',
                'operator' => 'IN',
            )
        ),
    ));
```

Then I do a simple calculation to find out how many to remove based on `if( $total_new > $min_new_products)` & `$remove_qty = abs($total_new - $min_new_products)` - "min_new_products" being set manually to "10" to make sure there are always at least 10 products tagged with "New":

```
//Set the minimum number of new products to leave
    $min_new_products = 10;
    $total_new = count($new_product_ids);
    
    if( $total_new > $min_new_products){
        // No. to remove
        $remove_qty = abs($total_new - $min_new_products);
```

Finally, I start a counter  and open a `foreach` loop to get an array of product tags and remove the "New" tag, using `break` to exit the loop when the counter is >= `$remove_qty`:

```
        // For each product remove New tag
        foreach ( $new_product_ids as $product_id ) {

            $all_current_tags = array();
            // get an array of the WP_Term objects for a defined product ID
            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_tag' );

            // Loop through each product tag for the current product
            if( count($terms) > 0 ){
                foreach($terms as $term){
                    $term_name = str_replace('"', "", $term->name);
                    
                    // Set the product tag names in an array
                    $all_current_tags[] = $term_name;
                }
            }       
            
            $key = array_search('New', $all_current_tags);
            unset($all_current_tags[$key]);
            
            $i++;
            if ($i >= $remove_qty){
                break;
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately, my code does not work... and I'm too much of a PHP novice to understand why or even how to debug it. Could anyone suggest how I could fix it?

Full code below:

```
// Untag old "New" products weekly
function mlabs_untag(){
    
    //Get products by tag
    $new_product_ids = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'New',
                'operator' => 'IN',
            )
        ),
    ));
    
    echo "<script>console.log('New Products Array: " . json_encode($new_product_ids) . "' );</script>";
    
    //Set the minimum number of new products to leave
    $min_new_products = 10;
    $total_new = count($new_product_ids);
    
    if( $total_new > $min_new_products){
        
        echo "<script>console.log('Total New: " . $total_new . "' );</script>";
        echo "<script>console.log('Min to Leave: " . $min_new_products . "' );</script>";
        
        echo "<script>console.log('Total is greater than min.');</script>";
        
        // No. to remove
        $remove_qty = abs($total_new - $min_new_products);
        
        echo "<script>console.log('No. to remove: " . $remove_qty . "' );</script>";
        
        // Start counter 
        $i = 0;
        // For each product remove New tag
        foreach ( $new_product_ids as $product_id ) {

            $all_current_tags = array();
            // get an array of the WP_Term objects for a defined product ID
            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_tag' );

            // Loop through each product tag for the current product
            if( count($terms) > 0 ){
                foreach($terms as $term){
                    $term_name = str_replace('"', "", $term->name);
                    
                    // Set the product tag names in an array
                    $all_current_tags[] = $term_name;
                }
            }
            
            echo "<script>console.log('Product Terms Array: " . json_encode($all_current_tags) . "' );</script>";
            
            
            $key = array_search('New', $all_current_tags);
            unset($all_current_tags[$key]);
            
            echo "<script>console.log('Product Terms Array Edited: " . json_encode($all_current_tags) . "' );</script>";

            
            $i++;
            if ($i >= $remove_qty){
                break;
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was very close... I forgot to set the product tags at the end with `wp_set_object_terms($product_id, $all_current_tags, 'product_tag');`

I also changed `'order' => 'DESC',` to `'order' => 'ASC',`